# Capturing screen of another windows user with python-mss

Tags: python-mss

I'm working on screen capture on Windows using Python and `mss`, and I'm wondering if I can capture the screen of another user on the same machine.

I have two windows users on the machine: one running a kiosk application in a browser on full screen continuously, and an admin user for all other tasks. I can only start my screen capture script from the admin user, but I would need to record the kiosk application.

I tried the naïve way, by starting capture and switching users, of course it keeps recording the admin user's screen.

Is there a way to do this, or is it fundamentally impossible due to the separation of users?

Answer (score 0):

I can't provide a code example, but I could imagine that running the code as either SYSTEM or as a Windows Service would make it "omnipotent" so to say. Then you use Python.NET to integrate/ link everything.